# iPad2 - Will not boot nor cold/hard reset

Tags: ipad

I have an iPad2 with me and I can't turn it on. Here are the behavior;

- Not shown in iTunes/Device Manager (I have Windows XP SP3)
- The sleep button will not show the slider to close the iPad.
- I see a light apple on the screen but not a solid one as when it boots up. When I
  press the sleep button and the home one, after 6 seconds, the light
  apple goes off but as soon as I released the home button, it came
  back. Nothing popping up on my PC screen tho...

The iPad is being charged for at least a full hours but still nothing. What can I do short of taking it in for repair?

Answer (score 1):

According to [HT1430](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1430) there isn't much more that you can do:

---

**Restarting your device**

- Press and hold the Sleep/Wake button for a few seconds until the red "slide to power off" slider appears, and then slide the slider.
- Press and hold the Sleep/Wake button until the Apple logo appears.

**Follow these steps to reset your device**

*Note: Reset your device only if it is no longer responding and the steps above do not work.*

- Press and hold the Sleep/Wake button and the Home button together for at least ten seconds, until the Apple logo appears.

---

Got an Apple Retail Store nearby for a visit to the Genius Bar?

Comment: Tried those steps. I think the only way to get outta this is the Apple Store.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing/describing as a "light Apple" is the result of a display that was displaying the logo, and then power was cut. The pixels are still displaying the image but there is no power to the device so nothing is backlit. Additionally, if you cannot get your device to boot, it is likely that something related to the power distribution has caused the device to stop working. No power = no boot. (This post reminds me of an old iPod video I used to have)

How do you charge your iPad? Does the bottom of the power brick say "10W USB Power Adapter"? If not, then that throws up a red flag right there.

Has your iPad been exposed to humidity or moisture (liquids) of any kind?

Has your power supply (the power to the building that powers the socket) experienced an outage or surge recently?

Any of these things could have caused the problem you are experiencing. Then again, it could also be something related to the display connection, firmware, etc.